# Command "chainlit run" doesn't start my python application

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

In the folder App, I have a file "app.py" with the below code (from https://docs.chainlit.io/get-started/pure-python):

```
import chainlit as cl
from chainlit import user_session


@cl.on_message
async def main(message: cl.Message):
    # Your custom logic goes here...

    # Send a response back to the user
    await cl.Message(
        content=f"Received: {message.content}",
    ).send()
```

I'm trying to run this file in a terminal (macos Sonoma, zsh) with command "chainlit -w run app.py" and I'm getting the below error:

*jarkow@MacBook-Air-Jarkow-2 App % chainlit run app.py -w*

*Usage: chainlit run [OPTIONS] TARGET*
*Try 'chainlit run --help' for help.*

*Error: Invalid value: File does not exist: chainlit_basics.py*

I installed the chainlit python package successfully and the command "chainlit hello" works well.

Comment: Try `python -m chainlit run app.py`